# React-router + electron Location "/" did not match any routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, electron

I just started with electron and I've been having difficulties integrating react-router with it. I keep on getting this warning whatever I do:

```
Warning: [react-router] Location "/" did not match any routes
```

Router:

```
"use babel"

import React from 'react'
import { Router, hashHistory } from 'react-router'

/* ******************
    IMPORTS
*********************/

import {routes} from './routes'

const App = () => {
    return (
      <Router history={hashHistory} routes={routes} />
    );
}

export default App
```

Routes:

```
"use babel"

import React from 'react'
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

/* ******************
    IMPORTS
*********************/

import App from './src/app.js'
import Root from './src/root'

export default (
    <Route path="/" component={Root} />
);
```

Root:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>test</div>
    );
  }
}
```

I noticed that react-router is adding the hashtag before the slash. I am pretty sure that I did a rookie mistake somewhere but I can't find out what's wrong...

URL: `file:///C:/wamp/www/electron_projects/projectOne/index.html#/`

I have read other similar questions but no luck. Your help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is a mismatch between the way you are importing and exporting, use either `named or default import/export`.

**Default import/export:**

```
import routes from './routes';
```

Define it like this in `routes.js`:

```
let routes = (
    <Route path="/" component={Root} />
);

export default routes;
```

**named import/export:**

```
import {routes} from './routes';
```

Define it like this in `routes.js`:

```
let routes = (
    <Route path="/" component={Root} />
);

export routes;
```

Since your are returning all the routes by App component, so render that component by `ReactDOM.render`, like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Read the difference between these two: https://danmartensen.svbtle.com/build-better-apps-with-es6-modules

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting your routes like this:

```
export default (
    <Route path="/" component={Root} />
);
```

Therefore you need to import them like this:

```
import routes from './routes'
```

Default exports are unnamed, and therefore need to be imported without brackets. If you surround it with brackets, it looks for a *named* export.

**Update**

It's worth noting that you can import them by any name you choose. It's an *unnamed* export, so it doesn't matter what you name the import. You could (but wouldn't) import it like this instead:

```
import foo from './routes'
```

And it wouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be using your Router component in your code, the place where rendering into dom via `ReactDOM`. 
Please check below the working code snippet.

```js
let Router = ReactRouter.Router;
let RouterContext = Router.RouterContext;
let Route = ReactRouter.Route;

const Root = (props) => {
  return (
        <div>
           <h1>test</h1>
        </div>
    );
};


const routes = (
       <Route path="/" component={Root} /> 
);


const router = (
<Router history={ReactRouter.hashHistory} routes={routes}/>
);


ReactDOM.render(
router, 
document.getElementById('test'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/3.0.0/ReactRouter.min.js"></script>

<div id="test"></div>
```